# Cordova deviceReady not firing on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am currently developing on my new Mac with Cordova, but I am facing a problem that is hardly discussed here and in other forums.
When I try to simulate my App with Xcode in a Simulator it works pretty fine. But when I run it on the device the deviceready isn't fired at all.

I already searched for different solutions:

- Remove and re-add all Plugins: done
- Set Content-Security-Policy in the index.html

I got an old, working project as well but I could not find any hints or major differences.

Unfortunately, I could not solve the problem.

Does anyone else have the same issue or has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: create a new cordova project, simply put alert('Hello'); inside the deviceready(), can you see Hello in your device?

Comment: There are so many things that could be going wrong, and you aren't giving enough information to debug this. Try running it from XCode and see what you see in the log (and if that doesn't help, post what you see here).